# Can we get 'ambient' values from routes in Blazor.WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

As written in the title, I'm trying to get some values from routes in blazor, which should be available to all pages. Think "culture-select" or "multi-tenancy" or similar.

E.g. with `/base/{culture}/my/fancy/page` or `/base/{my-tenant}/their/fancy/page`
I'd like to have the content of `{culture}` or `{my-tenant}` available as `<CascadingValue>` or bindable parameter.

I could probably use a base-class or anything to work around the issue, but I'd hope there's a way, that won't make it neccessary to implement an own router or route-parser to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the MainLayout component's OnParametersSet method, capture the parameter values avaialble in the `RouteValues` object, and pass them to the CascadingValue component's Value attribute property to be cascaded to children...

```
@code
{

    private string Culture{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // pull out the "culture" parameter from the route data
        object culture = null;
        if ((this.Body.Target as 
        RouteView)?.RouteData.RouteValues?.TryGetValue("Culture", out 
          culture) == true)
        {
            Culture = culture?.ToString();
        }
       
    }
    // Note: The first argument to `TryGetValue` is the parameter name
    // defined in the in page with the route template 
    // `/base/{culture}/my/fancy/page`
    // It is not the local `Culture` property we use in MainLayout to pass to 
    // the CascadingValue component's Value attribute property, right ;}

}
```

And the view portion of MainLayout may look something like this:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            @Header
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may use `this` instead of `Culture` to pass a reference to the MainLayout, define the CascadingParameter as of type MainLayout in the children components, and access the the Culture property like this:

```
var culture = MainLayout.Culture;
```

Note: In your example you can define a class in order to cascade `{culture} and {my-tenant}`

Comment: Oh - that looks like a proper workaround :)  
Would I need to define all `@page` directives to include the parameter then?

Comment: I guess by saying `a proper workaround` you mean that it is not the formal way of getting routes values that you're expecting, right ? No such formal way exists. There is no method of the router or any related objected that you can do it. You have to parse the route values, and the best and proper way to do that is from the location I use in my code sample... Not sure I uderstand the question, but let me try...

Comment: Do you mean that in the following url (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you think that `en-us` should not appear, and yet the url would redirect the user to the English edition?  What if the user is a German :) You must always include the culture parameter in each of your pages, unless you design your site to contain subsites, for each culture, and the redirection is done from within the Startup class. But that is entirely out of the scope of the current question.

Comment: I had hoped there was a way to define something like an "app base route" or "section base url" or something like that (I think angular allows that), but since it's only 4 or 5 pages in my case, I'll take your solution :)